# Project which uses CocoaPods doesn't compile

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to build a project which uses CocoaPods. When I run build process I'm getting error

```
    Parse Issue
    Uknown type name 'link'
```

When I look at file which led to this issue it is .h file but it contains this

```
link ../../AFNetworking/AFNetworking/AFNetworkReachabilityManager.h
```

This "link" doesn't seem to me a regular command which can be found within .h file and probably this .h file should be pre-processed with some other tool before normal compilation process.
I'm using XCode 6.1.1, base SDK iOS 8.1.
Please help me how to deal with it if you've faced something similar before or if you know why this .h has link command.
Thanks!

**SOLUTION**
To solve this issue I just had to perform

```
    $ pod install
```

Comment: open workspace, not project

Comment: Yes, Andrey I'm opening workspace. Not a project. The workspace has 2 projects. One of them is CocoaPods and another is the one which I actually need to build. Any other ideas? Why .h file in CocoaPods contains "link" word? Which program should process such .h files? Thanks!

Comment: That project is broken.

Comment: @mostruash I don't think so. There are lot of .h files which have similar content and all of them are referencing to other .h files with same names but stored at different location. Looks like such .h with link command are just shortcuts to actual .h files.